# Get the local date format as a string

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsdateformatter

I want a method that returns the local date format as a string.

E.g., the method would return the string "dd/MM/yyyy" for UK users and "MM/dd/yyyy" for USA users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `NSDateFormatter`'s [dateFormatFromTemplate:options:locale:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter/1408112-dateformatfromtemplate?language=objc) method. This takes a template containing the elements of the date you wish included and returns the appropriate format for the supplied locale.